# what cryption does windows(vista/7/8) use to store wi-fi passwords?

Tags: windows-7, windows, wireless-networking, encryption

That is located at c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Wlansvc\Profiles\Interfaces

here is one example:
01000000D08C9DDF0115D1118C7A00C04FC297EB010000007240CE1F0CB1AF4EA6CFB186ED28FFEB0000000002000000000010660000000100002000000027FEE52EF600D69092EB59679D3FAA07764BEAFA2B96645DFC25E3130A64FDB5000000000E8000000002000020000000A35C61A5F1B7BE8A465E90F099C7611C5F02DDFBB3E5CE4CCF48AFBC68D0E6EA100000009A9D79478B44F2B814804DA1C1AFF02140000000388A127A175044282E98EBA6F9F32339C0D7F2C37AD9D065F61F675764C6A2BF5E775C59F0E182BE238FC2A922A111D5D527949308107620550F84DF0FEF6D85

It has 460 chars. I need this so  I can find out my wi-fi password(on pc that im not admin) I know how it starts - what it might be etc. so I can just brute-force.

Comment: Can't you get to the WiFi key through the normal interface? You can click on a check box to show the characters.

Comment: use this tool to get the key: http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/wireless_key.html